# Why is 'ㅇ' needed?

Tags: grammar

Why do I need to use silent letter `ㅇ` in word `몽골` (Mongol)? Can I use `모골` instead? In general, when to use `ㅇ`?

Comment: This question lacks self-research efforts and reads too basic and its answer could be found in any dictionary or internet websites such as http://www.howtostudykorean.com/unit0/ and https://www.learnlangs.com/RWP/Korean/Korean%20-%20Lesson%201.htm.

Comment: Please try to learn how to read and write using readily available resources on the internet as listed in the above comment and ask a question specifically after you master reading and writing Hangeul. I don't think it is that difficult.

Comment: Hi vico - I'm afraid this is off-topic for the reasons Rathony mentioned. We now have our [on-topic](http://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page available - it wan't there when you posted, so don't worry! I hope the answer already posted here is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As you probably know, Korean letters are arranged in blocks. *Most* blocks are two or three letters, either:

- **consonant-vowel** - e.g.:

### 가, 고

- **consonant, vowel, consonant** - e.g.:

### 목, 막

ㅇ *is* silent when it is the first consonant in a block. So if you want a block's sound to start with a vowel, you must write the block starting with ㅇ. an example is the 안 ('an') in '안녕'

When 'ㅇ' is the *last* in a block, as in 몽, it is **not** silent. It is a [velar nasal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velar_nasal), or 'ng' sound. So if you want a block's sound to end in 'ng' - like the 'mo**ng**' in 몽골 - then you can use the 'ㅇ' for that purpose.